# Get Summation using in keyword in Sqlite Database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, join

Need to get the total sum and count of the rows using join query while searching with tags ids.
Search can be done using multiple tag ids.I am trying to do it using 'in' keyword but it is returning wrong summation not able to understand how to get the summation while joining tables

Query 1:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Total,count(*) as count FROM 
tbl_transactions
where trans_type='Expenses' and DATE(date) BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-12-10'  
AND trans_type='Expenses'
```

returns the right value as there is no joining

Query 2:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Total,count(*) as count FROM 
tbl_transactions g 
left join tbl_dummy2 d2
on d2.colA =g.trans_id
left join tbl_dummy d 
on d.dummy_id1=d2.colB
where trans_type='Expenses' and d2.colB in (1,2) and DATE(date) BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-12-10'  
AND trans_type='Expenses'
```

returns the wrong value as joining is not properly done

I have three table:

1. tbl_transactions which holds all the transaction
2. tbl_dummy which holds all the tags (master table)
3. tbl_dummy2 which holds the colA(trans_id) and colB(tagids)

[image: tbl_transactions]

[image: tbl_tags]

[image: temp_trans_tags]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition `d2.colB IN (1, 2)` in the `ON` clause, because when you have it in the `WHERE` clause it will return only the matching rows of the `LEFT JOIN` which is actually an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) as Total, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM tbl_transactions t 
LEFT JOIN tbl_dummy2 d2 on d2.colA = t.trans_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_dummy d1 on d1.dummy_id1 = d2.colB AND d2.colB IN (1, 2)
WHERE t.trans_type='Expenses'  AND DATE(t.date) BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-12-10'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jxFgJWTJJBzGC1vzaiCHEt/0).
Results:

```
| Total | count |
| ----- | ----- |
| 8585  | 2     |
```

Comment: it is not returning 8585.returning 25755  and count =4

Comment: @avik did you check the demo? For the sample data you posted this code returns the correct results.

Comment: yes checked. Did you tried using the same data by inserting it into sqllite?

Comment: Of course I did. This is what the demo does. Check the insert statements.